# Sqlalchemy filter on JSONB column by contains

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use a JSONB column and apply a `.contains`on it. This column value is a string list.

There is my model:

```py
class MessageDocument(Document):
    __tablename__ = "message"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    # ...
    concerned = Column(JSONB(), default="[]")  # list of str
```

And my query:

```py
.filter(MessageDocument.concerned.contains([character.id]))
```

But there is the error:

```
E       sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: json @> unknown
E       LINE 3: WHERE message.concerned @> '["xena"]' AND message.first_mess...
E                                       ^
E       HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I followed up many responses here but whithout success (`.astext`, `.as_text()`, `cast(...)`. How can I deal with my JSONB string list to do this `.contains`?

Comment: where that `@>` operand come from?

Comment: I think it is generated by sqlalchemy

Comment: Is this issue solved? Please tell what the solution was.

Comment: @SukanyaPai Hello, I think I didn't resolve it (it's from years). If I remember, I stored this data in raw text and done JSON things python side or used joined table.